# How to disable the responsive sorting filter style for v-data-table in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a v-data-table and come headers can be sorted. However, I found in a small screen all headers are turned to a drop down list by Vuetify. I don't want this feature, is there a option for me to disable? I want to bring all my headers back..

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add mobile-breakpoint value to your `<v-data-table>`, such as `<v-data-table mobile-breakpoint="0">`

Answer (score 3):

Add Style in Your Vue File without using 'Scope'

```css
     <style>
      .v-data-table-header-mobile{
        display: none !important;
      }
     </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

:disable-sort="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"